# Mongoid Complex Query Including Embedded Docs

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have a model with several embedded models. I need to query for a record to see if it exists. the issue is that I will have to include reference to multiple embedded documents my query would have to include the following params:

```
{
 "first_name"=>"Steve",
 "last_name"=>"Grove",
 "email_addresses"=>[
     {"type"=>"other", "value"=>"steve@stevegrove.com", "primary"=>"true"}
 ],
 "phone_numbers"=>[
     {"type"=>"work_fax", "value"=>"(720) 555-0631"},
     {"type"=>"home", "value"=>"(303) 555-1978"}
 ],
 "addresses"=>[
     {"type"=>"work", "street_address"=>"6390 N Main Street", "city"=>"Elbert", "state"=>"CO"}
 ],
}
```

How can I query for all the embedded docs even though some fields are missing such as _id and associations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to think about.

1. Are you sure the query HAS to contain all these parameters? Is there not a subset of this information that uniquely identifies the record? Say (`first_name`, `last_name`, and an `email_addresses.value`). It would be silly to query all the conditions if you could accomplish the same thing in less work.
2. In Mongoid the [where](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#where) criteria allows you to use straight javascript, so if you know how to write the javascript criteria you could just pass a string of javascript to where.
3. Else you're left writing a really awkward where criteria statement, thankfully you can use the dot notation.

Something like:

```
UserProfile.where(first_name: "Steve", 
                   last_name: "Grove", 
                   :email_addresses.matches => {type: "other", 
                                                value: "steve@stevegrove.com", 
                                                primary: "true"}, 
                    ..., ...)
```

Comment: I would love to see an example of what the js criteria would look like.

Answer (score 0):

in response to the request for embedded js:

```
query = %{
  function () {
    var email_match = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.email_addresses.length && !email_match; i++){
      email_match = this.email_addresses[i].value === "steve@stevegrove.com";
    }
    return this.first_name === "Steve" &&
      this.last_name === "Grove" &&
      email_match;
  }
}
UserProfile.where(query).first
```

It's not pretty, but it works

Answer (score 0):

With Mongoid 3 you could use `elem_match` http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html#symbol

```
UserProfile.where(:email_addresses.elem_match => {value: 'steve@stevegrove.com', primary: true})
```

This assumes

```
class UserProfile
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :email_addresses
end
```

Now if you needed to include every one of these fields, I would recommend using the `UserProfile.collection.aggregate(query)`. In this case you could build a giant hash with all the fields.

```
query = { '$match' => {
  '$or' => [
    {:email_addresses.elem_match => {value: 'steve@stevegrove.com', primary: true}}
  ]
} }
```

it starts to get a little crazy, but hopefully that will give you some insight into what your options might be. https://coderwall.com/p/dtvvha for another example.